# How to procedurally generate deterministic, easily differentiable terrain?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polynomials, continuity, fourier-analysis

For my A-Level computer science project I'm making an arcade game in which I need to generate a heightmap for 3D terrain.
Originally I tried using a sum of sine curves (with randomly initialised x and y scale factors) as I need it to be easily differentiable (players are modelled as spheres rolling along the terrain so I need to know the gradient to calculate the portion of weight acting down the slope) but this doesn't provide a high enough periodicity or level of detail.
So without a very high number of sine curves to sum (which is very computationally expensive) this doesn't seem to really work.
Using a high degree polynomial is also difficult as the terrain should maintain roughly the same average height as the game progresses.
I need to be able to initialise an equation for the curve at the start of the game and then base all calculations on that since terrain generation should be deterministic (unloading then reloading the same chunk should generate same terrain without having to store it in memory) so I don't think I can just use Perlin Noise unfortunately.
Any ideas for alternate methods?

Comment: I would set your elevation grid to gaussian random variables generated from a known seed, then I would do a gaussian blur with a specified size. This would produce deterministic terrain with controlled slopes and magnitudes which is differentiable everywhere

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the sum of sine functions provide not enough periodicity, or too much? Given that every periodic function is a sum of sines, I'd be somewhat surprised if you meant the former, although if you did I'd be curious to hear exactly what you meant.

Comment: Also, I want to throw out the idea of some sort of 2D/3D cubic splines, since I think cubic splines would be my first guess as to how to solve the problem of constructing such a heightmap for 2D terrain. This would have the property that, locally, the surface near each point is very simple to compute (i.e. it's just a cubic). I'm sure there's a reasonable higher-dimensional analogue. For the problem of being deterministic, you could always fix the seed of the randomness at the beginning of the generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, written in Python, of how to generate such a hilly landscape as a Gaussian field. One generates a discrete field of psuedorandom variables and blurs it to introduce correlations. This field could easily be interpolated (to make it continuous) or differentiated. A Sobel filter is a cheap way to differentiate such a discrete field.

[image]